# Run home assistant in an iframe (on a local KIOSK-RPi)

Tags: cors, http-headers

Like this question ( [Run Home Assistant in an iframe](https://community.home-assistant.io/t/run-home-assistant-in-an-iframe/309482)), I'm intrested in running my Home Assistant in an `<iframe />`.

This is my situation:

1. I access my Home Assistant locally by typing `http://10.0.0.6:8123` in my browser. That works fine!
2. Another project I'm working on, is to have Home Assistant in an `<iframe />` on a KIOSK. This is what I want to access:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <iframe src="http://10.0.0.6:8123" title="Home Assistant"></iframe>
        <my-calendar> ... </my-calendar>
        <other-stuff> ... </other-stuff>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fig.1 - index.html

**Goal**:
I would like to be able to type `http://10.0.0.50/index.html` (`10.0.0.50` is my webserver) in any browser on my network

**Problem**:
I can reach my page (`http://10.0.0.50/index.html` ) but Home Assistant does not show up:
**`Refused to display 'http://10.0.0.6:8123/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`** (browser log).

I understand that I probably (?) need to manipulate the http integration and maybe the setting `use_x_frame_options` someway?

This is what I have right now:

```
http:
  cors_allowed_origins:
    - http://10.0.0.9  
  use_x_forwarded_for: true
  trusted_proxies:
    - 172.30.33.0/24
```

What should I add/change/remove?